# $\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\sum _{i=0}^n\frac{1}{f_{i}(n)}\right)$

Tags: limits

I would like to be given a helping hand with regard to solving this problem, that is finding the value of the following limit:
$$\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\sum _{i=0}^n\frac{1}{n+2^i}\right)$$
In my opinion and view, I suppose that it is $0$, but I would need a complete proof, not just speculation.
This is what I tried.

$$\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\sum _{i=0}^n\frac{1}{n+2^i}\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty \:\:}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+4}+...+\frac{1}{n+2^n}\right)\ge 0\left(obvious\right)$$

and then I need an upper bound.

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{i = 0}^n {\frac{1}{{n + 2^i }}}  = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{\left[ {\sqrt n } \right] - 1} {\frac{1}{{n + 2^i }}}  + \sum\limits_{i = \left[ {\sqrt n } \right]}^n {\frac{1}{{n + 2^i }}}  \le \frac{{\sqrt n }}{{n + 1}} + \frac{n}{{n + 2^{\sqrt n } }}
$$

Comment: @Gary Both limit terms $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: @herbsteinberg Yes, that was my goal.